# Regex: I have a flaw in my logic

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match a pattern where the non word characters in the first bracket never repeat and the pattern must end with a the second set in the brackets. I just don't understand why this test case is failing:

```
regexString = '([\-\._]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*'
rgx = re.compile(regexString)
assert(rgx.match('dan--') == None)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation for re.match: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match
If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding MatchObject instance.

In your case '([-._]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*' clearly matches 'dan' part of 'dan--' hence the result is not None but a MatchObject. If you don't want it to match anything other than what's in your group put your group between ^ and $.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check that the pattern match the whole string use `^`, `$` anchor.

```
>>> import re
>>> regexString = r'^([\-\._]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$'
>>> rgx = re.compile(regexString)
>>> rgx.match('dan--')
>>> rgx.match('dan')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000029E0D50>
```

BTW, `^` is not strictly required becasue [`match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) matches only at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

`[\-\._]?` is one or none of the following characters which are in the brackets, which must be followed by one or more letter or number. Anything or nothing of all of the stuff in parentheses will match nothing, as well. But, `rgx.match('dan--') == None` fails because you it's okay to have `--` after `dan` since your not specifying if anything should come after `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`. You need anchors. If you don't mind the underscore the you could change `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` to `(\w|\d)+`.

```
'^([\-\.]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$'

# also matches '-underscore_dan'
'^([\-\.]?(\w|\d)+)*$'
```

Comment: Yes it should fail but doesn't, that's why it doesn't pass the assertion.

Answer (score 0):

Try to match `'--dan--'`. This would indeed fail and the result of the assertion would be true.

Reason is the `?`, meaning **zero** or **one** (but not two or more).